# What is wrong with the current sed command for parsing an HTML?

Tags: linux, sed

Here is the part of 1.html

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
      <td><center><h3 id="nr_status">FAILED<h3></center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <b>1 tests have been read.</b><br />
    <b>1 tests have been executed.</b><br />
    <b>0 tests have been ignored.</b><br />
    <b>0 tests have suceeded.</b><br />
    <b>1 tests have failed.</b><br />
```

I do not know much about linux but I was exploring StreamEditor, the objective is to set the value `FAILED` in a variable. So I tried to write a code

```
sed -n '/<h3 id="nr_status">/,/<\/h3>/p'  ~/1.html
```

The output i got is everything after `<td>` , not sure why is not `<h3>` being considered as a matching pattern ?

Comment: Don't use regex but an XML/HTML parser

Comment: @GillesQuenot - how can i check which html packages are installed on linux machine. Also if my html target tag is fairly static, is sed not a reasonable option ?

Comment: No, sed is not an option. Have you tried my 2 solutions below ? Which distro/version ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot - replied to your comment below, it --xpath is recognized on OL7 and not on OL6, however the problem is that the tag is <h3> and not </h3>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a proper XML/HTML parser and a XPath query:

```
xmllint --xpath '//table/tr/td/center/h3[@id="nr_status"]/text()' file.html
```

If you use an old version of `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --shell file.html<<EOF | sed '1d;$d;s/^ ------- *$//;/^$/d'
cat //table/tr/td/center/h3[@id="nr_status"]/text()
EOF
```

or :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//table/tr/td/center/h3[@id="nr_status"]/text()' file.html
```

## Output:

```
FAILED
```

I created an HTML file using your snippet in `file`:

```
xmlstarlet fo -H -R file > file.html
```

The file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
        <td>
          <center>
            <h3 id="nr_status">XXX<h3/></h3>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <b>1 tests have been read.</b>
    <br/>
    <b>1 tests have been executed.</b>
    <br/>
    <b>0 tests have been ignored.</b>
    <br/>
    <b>0 tests have suceeded.</b>
    <br/>
    <b>1 tests have failed.</b>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

## If the HTML is broken

You can pass it to [tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) to fix it before:

```
tidy -m file.html
```

(edit *in place*)

Comment: The first one with xmllint doesnot recognize --xpath option.

Comment: @Giles - version OL6 , then i tried your solution on OL7. It recognized xpath but i think the problem is that the ending tag is <h3> and not </h3>

Comment: Sorry, i dont have xmlstarlet.

Comment: You can install it, or use Perl

Comment: Or using `tidy` like I added to my post to fix broken HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216826/discussion-between-userx-and-gilles-quenot).

Comment: Added a solution to use `xmllint` even with no `--xpath` switch

Comment: Perhaps specify which h3: `h3[@id="nr_status"]`